# What happens if my co-op partner is behind or further in the campaign when we start co-op campaign?

Tags: forza-horizon-3

A friend and I started co-op campaign last night right when we unlocked the ability to play online. He was able to join my session and we did a bunch of races together. Between loading screens, I saw a message or tip that said any co-op campaign will also be applied to single player campaign.

If that is true, what happens if he joins my campaign later after I played a few races and unlocked new venues?  Does this overwriting his single player campaign by using my further progressed campaign?  I ask as I don't either of us to miss out on content or lock any achievements.

Comment: AFAIK from my own similar situation, it does not override progress. It only adds to their progress if your partner completes a mission they havent completed yet

Comment: Essentially, if either of you have trouble with a race, you can jump in the other persons game and help them complete it, or they can jump in yours,and it should have the same effect if either one of you wins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested this with a friend, and it seems that in co-op campaign you are simply working together on your individual campaigns. Whoever hosts the co-op session will be the one to start events, and you can only play the events they have unlocked, but in terms of progression:

- If a race is completed in a co-op campaign that the guest and host both have unlocked, the race is completed for both players when they return to single player campaign
- If the guest has already completed that race in their single player campaign, it will still earn them credits and fans and XP, as well as overwrite their best time/lap etc. if they beat their record
- If the guest hasn't unlocked the race yet, when they eventually unlock the race, it will show as completed immediately in their single player campaign

I've only tested this with regular events, not showcases or anything special, but I assume they work the same way. I actually have a Bucket List challenge that is locked for me, but checked off as completed, because I assume I did it in someone else's game.